# How to to extract texts only from inside of the "Inverted Comma or Quotes" by using Notepad++

Tags: web, notepad++, ocr, notepad, data-entry

I have a text document. I want to extract texts only from inside of the "Inverted Comma or Quotes" by using Notepadd++ or any website

**For Eg:**

> Lorem "Football" ipsum dolor "Cricket" sit amet, consectetur "Tennis"
>   adipiscing "Asia" sed do "Europe" tempor "North America" ut labore
>   "South America" dolore "Australia" aliqua. Ut "Africa" ad minim
>   veniam.

**I want to Extract texts only from inside of the Inverted Comma or Quotes**

> Football Cricket Tennis Asia Europe North America South America
>   Australia Africa

**OR**

> "Football" "Cricket" "Tennis" "Asia" "Europe" "North America" "South
>   America" "Australia" "Africa"

So what I can do? Anybody can help me.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs do what you want, see http://www.rexegg.com/regex-tricks.html

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `".+?" ?(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
".+?"       # string surrounded with quotes, you can use [“"'‘].+?[“"'‘] to process other quotes
 ?          # optional space
(*SKIP)     # skip what it was matching before
(*FAIL)     # force the failing of regex
  |           # OR
.           # 1 any character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can you paste all above codes together here ?

Comment: @user2996362: Sorry, I don't get you ! The regex is here. Just copy/paste it.

Comment: Can you paste above regex together. ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean with “paste above regex together”? The regex is in the answer, just copy it and paste it in your Notepad++. What are you trying to do? I give you the solution of your problem, just use it. Just follow the seven step I gave you.

Comment: You know a solution for this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477359/how-can-i-extract-specific-texts-from-an-html-file-by-using-notepad-or-adobe-d