# How can I extract specific texts from an HTML file by using Notepad++ or Adobe Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, notepad++, ocr, dreamweaver, data-entry

.

I want to extract the **ID** attribute from an HTML file by using Notepad++ or Dreamweaver. Delete all other texts.

**For Eg:**

```
<div id="header" class="header-blue sticky">
<div id="header-message" class="alert alert-dismissible">
<form id="contact-form" class="custom-form" method="POST" action="https://www.google.com">
<input id="your-email" type="email" class="form-email"  placeholder="Your Email">
```

**I want to extract only ID attribute from HTML like this;**

```
id="header"
id="header-message"
id="contact-form"
id="your-email"
```

So what I can do? Please help me..

.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I searched in google to get a tool website. But I didn't get any website. :( :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<\w+[^>]+(id=".+?").*?>`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<\w+            # opening tag
[^>]+           # 1 or more not >
(id=".+?")      # group 1, id and value
.*?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
>               # close tag
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wow... It worked .. You are very intelligent. I don't have words for express my happiness.. Thank you very very much.. Thank you.. Thank you.. :) :)